# Vaadin gantt chart is not readable

Tags: vaadin, gantt-chart

I want to use the vaadin gantt chart component and used some of the code examples for a test.
I can create the object but is not readable

```
public class PlanningView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    // declare parent GUI
    private MainUI myUI;
    // declare navigator
    public Navigator navigator;
    // declare menubar
    public MenuGenerator menubar;
    private TimeZone defaultTimeZone;

    private Gantt gantt;
    private NativeSelect reso;
    private DateField start;
    private DateField end;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");

    public PlanningView(Navigator navigator, MainUI myUI) {
        this.myUI = myUI;
        this.navigator = navigator;
        menubar = new MenuGenerator(this);

        VerticalLayout mainlayout = new VerticalLayout();

        gantt = new Gantt();
        gantt.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
        gantt.setHeight(500, Unit.PIXELS);
        gantt.setResizableSteps(true);
        gantt.setMovableSteps(true);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        gantt.setStartDate(cal.getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        gantt.setEndDate(cal.getTime());

        cal.setTime(new Date());
        Step step1 = new Step("First step");
        step1.setStartDate(cal.getTime().getTime());
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
        step1.setEndDate(cal.getTime().getTime());

        gantt.addStep(step1);


        mainlayout.addComponents(gantt);

        addComponent(mainlayout);
    }
    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Notification.show("Planning");
    }
    public void navigate(String page) {
        navigator.navigateTo(page);
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am also interested in exploring Vaadin Gantt chart, have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and after a while, I found the solution.

First, you have to add a `addons.scss` file to your theme

webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/addons.scss:

```
/* This file is automatically managed and will be overwritten from time to time. */
/* Do not manually edit this file. */

/* Provided by gantt-addon-1.0.1.jar */
@import "../../../VAADIN/addons/gantt/gantt.scss";


/* Import and include this mixin into your project theme to include the addon themes */
@mixin addons {
    @include gantt;
}
```

Afterward, modify your theme file:

webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/mystyle.scss:

```
@import "addons.scss";
@import "../../../VAADIN/addons/gantt/gantt-valo.scss";
@include addons;
@include gantt-valo;
```

Additionally, your widget set needs to inherit from the one of the gantt addon:

```
<module>
    <inherits name="org.tltv.gantt.WidgetSet" />
</module>
```

As you are using custom client side code, you have to add the client-compiler dependency to your build process:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Be aware of the vaadin-maven.plugin, which must be told to compile the widget set:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${com.vaadin_version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1G  -Xss1G</extraJvmArgs>
        <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
        <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</hostedWebapp>
        <compileReport>true</compileReport>
        <strict>true</strict>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>resources</goal>
                <goal>update-theme</goal>
                <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```